# Programmatically creating a new user on Mac OS using Objective-C or any Cocoa API?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm trying to create new user within my Application. I know that is possible using dscl and NSTask.But does anyone know how it is possbile to do with any Cocoa API , or programmaticaly using objective-c? within code , not using bash commands , like here

```
sudo niutil -create / /users/newuser 
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser uid 502
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser gid 502
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser realname "Longer Name"
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser home "/Users/newuser "
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser shell "/bin/tcsh"
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/sharedDir shell "Public"
sudo niutil -createprop / /users/newuser passwd "*"
sudo passwd newuser 
sudo ditto /System/Library/User\ Template/English.lproj /Users/newuser 
sudo chown -R newuser :group /Users/newuser
```

I was told that is possible to do using **Open Directory Framework**, but couldn't find usefull documentation. Thanks.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid issuing commands?  You can't do privileged operations from Cocoa anyway, and the above commands sound easier than using some funny Open Directory API.

Comment: I'm doing priveeged operations from Cocoa using Authorization services. Open Directory API seems to be not funny, I just can't find good documentation or tutorial for it. The reason I'm avoiding issuing commands, because Application needs to be run on MAC OS 10.5,10.6,10.7

Comment: First hit on google for Open Directory Framework is Apple's doc but framework is only for 10.6+

Comment: Thanks for advice. The framework is only for 10.6 , it means you should use Xcode version for at least 10.6,but it still runnable for 10.5. Apple's doc for Open Directory is confusing, couldn't figure out. Any tutorial or idea for Open Directory will be appreciated. Or something else to create user, and be able to check if it is created, or no.

Comment: What prevents you from issuing commands? If I recall correctly, `dscl` exists since 10.5 and hasn't disappeared yet. If you need to support older versions too, you can check the version of OS X using the [Gestalt API](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?DeterminingOSVersion) and then call either `niutil` or `dscl` accordingly.

Comment: Thanks I have also tried using dscl.But I was told that is better use API then using bash commands in Application. I wonder if anyone has ever used Open Directory Framework.

Comment: I'm interested if there was an answer to this in the 6 years since

Comment: @BenLeggiero Me too! Basically so far I managed to create an ODNode and query it. I’m currently searching how to create a new user.