# Manage local user accounts

Tags: linux, windows, macos, node.js, user-accounts

Assuming node is running as root, how do I:

- Add a new local (OS) user account and get its uid?
- Delete an account by name?

The accounts will be used for daemon processes, so they needn't be full-fledged user accounts.

Doing this on Linux is priority one, doing it on OS X would be nice, and super bonus for supporting Windows.

On Linux, I suppose you could just spawn `useradd`, but how would you determine the new user's uid?  Would it be better (or worse) to modify `/etc/passwd` and friends directly?

On Windows, it looks like [`NetUserAdd`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370649(v=vs.85).aspx) is the right place to look; has someone already written an addon to call it?

Answer (score 1):

For Linux, once you've created the account with `useradd`, you could call `getent passwd <username>` to see all the main relevant account details, including, in the 3rd field, the uid.

Example:

`# useradd -c "Jamie Carter" jamiec`

`# getent passwd jamiec`

yields:

jamiec:x:2722:500:Jamie Carter:/home/jamiec:/bin/false

To grab the uid in a one liner, you could combine the cut command to grab the 3rd field while treating `:` as the delimiter:

`$ getent passwd jamiec | cut -d: -f 3`

2722

Generally it's much safer and easier not to manipulate /etc/passwd and friends directly. Most of what you would need to do is likely already in a system command somewhere. For example, `userdel <username>` will delete an account by name from /etc/passwd, but also takes care of removing the user from /etc/groups so you don't have orphaned information left there. (You would have to deal with this yourself if you wrote your own user-deleter.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a big & broad question (MacOS, Windows, Linux all together), but to [create a new user from the command line on the Macintosh is not trivial](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20030603190314390) and [would require you to be authenticated as root / admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546451/programmatically-creating-a-new-user-on-mac-os-using-objective-c-or-any-cocoa-ap).

Comment: And I'm not certain how to do this on the Linux and/or Windows side.  Perhaps you could reformulate your question into three questions, one for each architecture, and describe what attempts or code you've tried so far?

Comment: Is it any easier on OS X if the user account need not be actually logged in to interactively, but only used as the target of `setuid`?